# React Js functional component return nothing

Tags: reactjs

I have created an app to let users to upload a csv and it will transform to network by react-graph-vis.

The csv will be in the following format

```
Buyer,Seller,Shares
A,B,20
C,A,30
P,D,60
D,A,10
```

The App I have created

```
import React from "react";
import { CSVReader } from "react-papaparse";
import Graph from "react-graph-vis";
function App() {
  var handleOnDrop = data => {
    var dataObject = data.slice(1);
    var tradeList = [];
    dataObject.forEach(element =>
      tradeList.push({
        to: element.data[0],
        from: element.data[1],
        shares: Number(element.data[2])
      })
    );
    var traderList = [];
    var netTradeList = [];
    tradeList.forEach(element => {
      traderList.push(element.to);
      traderList.push(element.from);
    });
    traderList = [...new Set(traderList)];
    let counter = 0;
    for (var i of traderList) {
      var score = 0;
      var netObject = {};
      netObject["id"] = counter;
      counter++;
      for (const j of tradeList) {
        if (i === j.to) {
          score = score + j.shares;
        }
        if (i === j.from) {
          score = score - j.shares;
        }
      }

      netObject["label"] = i;
      netObject["value"] = score;
      if (score > 0) {
        netObject["color"] = "Green";
      } else {
        netObject["color"] = "Red";
      }
      netTradeList.push(netObject);
    }
    GraphGeneration(netTradeList, tradeList);
  };

  const handleOnError = (err, file, inputElem, reason) => {
    console.log(err);
  };

  const handleOnRemoveFile = data => {
    console.log("---------------------------");
    console.log(data);
    console.log("---------------------------");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>
          <p>Network Creation</p>
          <p>Upload the file you want to create network</p>
        </div>
        <>
          <h5>Click and Drag Upload</h5>
          <CSVReader
            onDrop={handleOnDrop}
            onError={handleOnError}
            addRemoveButton
            onRemoveFile={handleOnRemoveFile}
          >
            <span>Drop CSV file here or click to upload.</span>
          </CSVReader>
        </>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

function GraphGeneration(netTradeList, tradeList) {
  console.log(tradeList);
  var graph = {
    nodes: netTradeList,
    edges: tradeList
  };
  var options = {
    layout: {
      hierarchical: true
    },
    edges: {
      color: "#000000"
    },
    interaction: { hoverEdges: true }
  };

  const events = {
    select: function(event) {
      var { nodes, edges } = event;
      console.log("Selected nodes:");
      console.log(nodes);
      console.log("Selected edges:");
      console.log(edges);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Graph
        graph={graph}
        options={options}
        events={events}
        getNetwork={network => {
          //  if you want access to vis.js network api you can set the state in a parent component using this property
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I expect as the nodes and edges object (netTradeList,tradeList) generated and pass to GraphGeneration function, it will return a generated  and display on the website. However, when I upload the file the graph did not appear on the website. I would like to know which part have I done wrongly. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: debug your code to see if the `Graph` is rendered or not, if it is check if `graph = { nodes: netTradeList, edges: tradeList };` contains a valid data.

Comment: I know Graph is not rendered, but I don't know why, I have checked graph contains valid data. Thank you